# Explanation for Tauberian theorems for Laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform, tauberian-theorems

I am struggling with the following theorem in Feller's book "Probability Theory and its Applications". The tauberian theorem is written as follow :

> Let $F : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ of bounded variation, $p \geq 0$ be real number and
> $$\omega_F(s) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-st} d F(t).$$
> Then each of the relations
> $$ \dfrac{\omega_F(\tau \lambda)}{\omega_F(\tau)} \to \lambda^{-p}\hspace{15pt} \text{as $\tau \to 0$}.$$
> $$ \dfrac{F(tx)}{F(t)} \to x^{p} \hspace{15pt} \text{as $t \to \infty$}.$$
> implies the other as well as
> $$ \omega_F(1/t) \sim F(t) \Gamma(p+1) \hspace{15pt} \text{as $t \to \infty$}.$$

### My question

I want to be sure that I correctly understand this theorem.

Is it correct to say that if it exists $\lambda$ and $\rho$ such that:

$$ \dfrac{\omega_F(\tau \lambda)}{\omega_F(\tau)} \to \lambda^{-p}\hspace{15pt} \text{as $\tau \to 0$}$$

then, **for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$, we have**:

$$ \dfrac{F(tx)}{F(t)} \to x^{p} \hspace{15pt} \text{as $t \to \infty$    ?}$$

*What is said above is obvioulsy one of the implication, my question is on the "for all $x$"*

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct understanding of this theorem (Theorem 1 in Section 5 of Chapter XII of Vol. 2 of Feller's book) is a s follows:

> For each real $\rho\ge0$ the following two statements are equivalent to each other:
>
> - for each real $\lambda>0$,
>   $$\frac{\omega_F(\tau\lambda)}{\omega_F(\tau)}\to\lambda^{-\rho}\quad \text{as $\tau\to0$}$$
> - for each real $x>0$,
>   $$\frac{F(tx)}{F(t)}\to x^\rho \quad \text{as $t \to \infty$.}$$

This is clear from the proof of the mentioned theorem, which is based on the extended continuity theorem (Theorem 2a in Section 1 of Chapter XII of Vol. 2 of Feller's book). It is also clear from the proof of the extended continuity theorem that $F$ should be assumed a nondecreasing function.

Comment: Thank you @Iosif Pinelis ! Do you think that it is also true if we know this limit only on $\lambda\in[1,+\infty)$ ?

Comment: @NancyBoy : Yes, it is enough to only consider in the first statement the values of $\lambda\in[1,\infty)$ -- because any positive real number is the ratio of two real numbers $\ge1$. Instead of $1$, here you can use any real $\lambda_0>0$.

Comment: Thank you again for this clear answer! @Iosif Pinelis